# INSERT INTO statement is not working in C# , trying to insert into an Access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, insert

I've been trying to insert data into a MS Access database and I can't see what is wrong with my insert statement. I checked all the values and they should be the same, I even tried a really simple statement with static values but it doesn't work anyways.

I've followed the syntax to the letter but I still keep getting an `INSERT INTO` error when I get to the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` command.

```
string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\B8328\source\repos\KaihatsuEnshuu\KaihatsuEnshuu\OI21Database1.accdb";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str);

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO order (orderEmpno, orderCustomerId) VALUES (@orderEmpno, @orderCustomerId)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderEmpno", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderCustomerId", comboBox2.SelectedValue);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("An order has been started");
```

Comment: What is the complete and exact error you're getting? One thing that jumps out is the fact the table is called `Order` and this is a **reserved keyword** in SQL. In SQL Server, you'd have to put this in square brackets - `INSERT INTO [Order] (...)` , not sure what the syntax for MS Access is ....

Comment: try this `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [order] (orderEmpno, orderCustomerId) VALUES (?, ?)";`

Comment: OMG i tunneled vision so hard and I thought that the reserved words only applied to the words inside the table and not the table names themselves. Thank you !

Comment: Should not use reserved as names for anything.